# Open attribute table script in QGIS 3.6 graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, pyqgis-3

I am looking for a script which will allow me to open an attribute table of the final output of a graphical model in QGIS.

I know that you can use the following lines of code in the console but cannot find work out how to create a script from this that is accepted by the model:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
```

I want the output of my last stage in the model to be the input to this script so that the attribute table opens when finished.

Comment: the correct method is `activeLayer()` not `ActiveLayer()`

Comment: @FranRaga thanks I have now amended